# Issue with AJAX Hashbang

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've came across a problem with using a *'hashbang'* to keep track of which page has been loaded via AJAX.

When a link is clicked which loads content through an AJAX request into the content div, the hash of the URL changes to the page name. For example, if the user comes directly to pageA (*http://www.domain.com/pageA*) and then clicks a link for pageB, the URL will change to *http://www.domain.com/pageA#/pageB*

I'm using CodeIgniter for my application, and the code which handles the hash changing is in my header view, and it does the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.redirect = function() {
        if(window.location.hash.substring(0, 2) == "#!") {
            if(window.location.hash.substring(2).length > 2) {
                window.location = window.location.hash.substring(2);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    window.redirect();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(window).hashchange(function() {
            if(ajax_loading == true) {
                return false;
            } else {
                loadPage(window.location.hash.substring(2), 'internal', '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are two steps to this. The first one checks if there is a hashbang when coming directly to a page by refreshing, or entering the URL for example. If there is a hashbang, redirect to the page stored in the hash.

The second step checks for a change to the hash, which catches the likes of the user pressing the back button, for example.

My issue is with the first block - when a user refreshes or directly enters a URL with a hashbang.

If the user enters *http://www.domain.com/pageA#/pageB*, any server side code on *pageA* will run before the window is then redirected *pageB*

This is causing problems in cases such as:

1. User directly goes to *pageA* - *pageA* sets a session variable to '*abc*'
2. User clicks on link to *pageB* - *pageB* then sets that session variable to '*xyz*' - the URL is currently *http://www.domain.com/pageA#/pageB*
3. User clicks on link to *pageC* - the session variable is still set to '*xyz*' and *pageC* doesn't change this - the URL is currently *http://www.domain.com/pageA#/pageC*
4. User now hits refresh. *pageA* is executed first, before redirecting to *pageC* - but because *pageA* was executed first, the session variable has now been set back to '*abc*' when it should be '*xyz*'.

Due to loading the views at the last point of the code within a CodeIgniter controller - I can't do the window redirect at any point other than when the code of the page before the hashbang has executed.

Does any have any ideas of how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: This isn't really a problem with hashbangs, surely it's a problem with how you are controlling pages in your application? Why are you handling loading of pages like this?

Comment: It's an issue that has arose with the use of the hashbang. My question is how to handle the loading of pages in a similar way but without encountering the issue that I am.

Comment: A lot of these issues [can be solved with URL history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) instead of using hashes, but older browsers may have some issues with it (you could use [`history.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to get them up to par). However: if `GET`-ting a certain page yields different results depending on which page you previously visited, that is in my view a bit of a design flaw.  You'd have the same problem nevigating from pageA to pageC manually, so if should be solved for that case as well.

Comment: @Wrikken the problem is we need to support browsers which don't support HTML5, such as older versions of IE. When you say `You'd have the same problem nevigating from pageA to pageC manually` - you wouldn't. pageA would set the session to `abc`, and pageC would pick that value up at `abc` - no problem there!

Comment: Which is exactly what would happen if you load `pageA#pageC`... so, either that's _desired behavior_, or if it's not, you don't need a _single_ page in your hash, but a trail? (`pageA#pageB/pageC` or something like that.) Alternatively, if `pageA` knows about `pageB`, and only sets the variable to `abc` if it _is not already `xyz`_, this would work as well _for this case_, but makes the url not bookmarkable (and hence, in my opinion broken if used in `GET` requests).

Comment: Correct - but if they visit pageB in between loading `pageA` directly, and loading `pageC` via the AJAX link - `pageB` will set the session to `xyz`. If they press refresh, `pageA` will execute, reverting the session to `abc`, whereas because there is a hash (pageC), my desired action is to go directly to `pageC` and not execute `pageA`.

Comment: Yes, I understand your issue, I'm just trying to tell you that issue should be solved higher up. It's not an issue of your hash alone. Take this for instance: without all that hash rewriting, a use goes to `pageA`, `pageB` & then `pageC` in order, sees the `/pageC` url, wants to share that with another user, and gives him the url. That user has visited neither `pageA` or `pageB`, what happens on `pageC`? Most likely, it does something quite different then the original user saw. Which you should avoid. GET urls should be bookmarkable/shareable.

Comment: Something like using `/pageC?var=abc` or `/pageC?var=xyz` would work of course, be bookmarkable, etc. If you don't like query parameters in your url (some people go a bit overboard with 'seo-friendly-urls'), you could define a `/pageD` & `/pageE` which are essentially alliases for `/pageC?var=abc` & `/pageC?var=xyz`.

Comment: That's fine, the application is a user-only application, and pageA will always be visited and that session will always be there. It's purely an example to try and describe the issue I'm having in as simple a way as possible. I understand it needs to be solved higher up but due to the way the framework handles views, it seemed a bit of a catch-22 to me due to having to load the view last, but needing to run that JavaScript first. I'm going to try something along the lines of what Guillaume Royer answered and see what results I get.

Comment: @Wrikken I appreciate your input, but it's hard to explain the complete concept of the application. Everything is fine in terms of bookmarking, sharing links, etc. But the `GET` parameters wouldn't help solve the issue at all. In the actual application, the session parameter I talk of would actually be a filter applied to reports that the user runs (and could therefore be one of thousands of ID's, specific to the user). The only issue I have is the fact that the former page executes, overwriting anything set in the 'in-between' pages.

Comment: My point remains: your urls are not bookmarkable, and those filters _should_ IMHO be reflected in the URL. Being bookmarkable (and above that: indexable by search engines) is a big point of the internet, and sites who get this wroing (in this case: yours) are a source of frustration for users, and are hurting themselves in SEO rankings. If you don't want to go for it, this is fine, it's your application, you decide. It _is_ however how I personally think you should handle this.

Comment: Like I say the application is only available to our clients, there's no need for SEO, we don't want the application to be indexed by search engines. The URL's with the hashbangs in them, in most cases other than in the scenario I've explained in my question, are bookmarkable. The only issue is the one highlighted in my question.

Comment: I´ve given you a pointer of putting a trail rather then a single page in the hash if you don't want them bookmarkable. However: all bookmarkable urls have no issues, the one that isn't has. That is the last I'll say about it.

Comment: Again thanks for your help but I don't think you see where I'm coming from. The URL's ARE bookmarkable, because the hash bookmarks - and when loaded will load the correct page. The trail wouldn't be feasible in this case as the user could click through 50, or even 500 pages before reloading - and the hash has a maximum size, even if it didn't reach the maximum size it wouldn't look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't send user to http://www.domain.com/pageA#/pageC.

You should have a unique page, that does not set any session variable, and load other pages via AJAX. Then users never goes **directly to pageA** but through http://www.domain.com/index#/pageA.

1. User goes to /index#/pageA - pageA sets a session variable to 'abc'
2. User clicks on link to pageB - pageB then sets that session variable to 'xyz' - the URL is currently http://www.domain.com/index#/pageB
3. User clicks on link to pageC - the session variable is still set to 'xyz' and pageC doesn't change this - the URL is currently http://www.domain.com/index#/pageC
4. User now hits refresh. index is executed first, before redirecting to pageC - but because index does not set anything, the session variable is now still 'xyz'.

As I suppose you provides yourself the links to the user, there should be no problem setting it up.